# How detect change into arrays of object for each element?

Tags: algorithm, typescript2.0

I have an object array. I want to get for each element in the array the difference with the others.
For example thi is my object array:

```
array= [{id:1, name= 'test', isAdmin: true, userMail:'test@test.com', userTel: '+12555555'}, 
{id:1, name= 'test', isAdmin: false, userMail:'test@test.com', userTel: '+12555555'}, {id:1, 
name= 'test', isAdmin: false, userMail:'test@test.com', userTel: '+12555785444'}]
```

the result is :

```
result = [isAdmin, userMail, userTel]
```

I tried this solution but not working :

```
    for (let index = 0; index < this.array.length; index++) {        
        const e = this.array[index];            
                 let j = index + 1;
        let t;
        while (index !== j && j <= (this.array.length - 1) && t === undefined) {
            t = this.difference(array);
            j++;
        }
       let y;            
        if (t !== null && t !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(t).forEach(key => {
                if (key !== 'idTrace') {                    
                    y = key;
                }
            });
        }
         this.result.push(y);
    }

difference(object, base) {
    return transform(object, (result, value, key) => {
        if (!isEqual(value, base[key])) {
            result[key] = isObject(value) && isObject(base[key]) ? 
           this.difference(value, base[key]) : value;
        }
    });
}
```

Any help,  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this.

**Please note that this is not the most performant solution, but it is understandable (readable) solution on which you can make optimisations as needed.**

```js
const objects = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "isAdmin": true,
        "userMail": "test@test.com",
        "userTel": "+12555555"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "isAdmin": false,
        "userMail": "test@test123.com",
        "userTel": "+12555555"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "isAdmin": false,
        "userMail": "test@test.com",
        "userTel": "+12555785444"
    }
];

// Finds all the keys that are different in two objects.
const difference = (obj1, obj2) => {
    let foundKeys = [];
    Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => {
        if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
            foundKeys.push(key);
        }
    });
    return foundKeys;
};

let differentKeys = [];

// Compares every object with all objects and pushes to one array all differences in keys.
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < objects.length; j++) {
        differentKeys = differentKeys.concat(difference(objects[i], objects[j]));
    }
}

// Removes duplicates.
differentKeys = differentKeys.filter(function(value, index, differentKeys) {
    return differentKeys.indexOf(value) === index;
});

console.log(differentKeys);
```

Let me know if you have any questions.